# Error on Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello everyone I am developing an android app and I am new to this development.
I am facing on error which says:

**Error:(134, 19) error: RecyclerTouchListener is not abstract and does not override abstract method onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean) in OnItemTouchListener**

Here is my code from where the above error appears

FragmentDrawer.java

```
public class FragmentDrawer extends Fragment {

    private static String TAG = FragmentDrawer.class.getSimpleName();

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter;
    private View containerView;
    private static String[] titles = null;
    private FragmentDrawerListener drawerListener;

    public FragmentDrawer() {

    }

    public void setDrawerListener(FragmentDrawerListener listener) {
        this.drawerListener = listener;
    }

    public static List<NavDrawerItem> getData() {
        List<NavDrawerItem> data = new ArrayList<>();


        // preparing navigation drawer items
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            NavDrawerItem navItem = new NavDrawerItem();
            navItem.setTitle(titles[i]);
            data.add(navItem);
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // drawer labels
        titles = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_labels);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflating view layout
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
       recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);

        adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                drawerListener.onDrawerItemSelected(view, position);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(containerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));

        return layout;
    }


    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
        containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset / 2);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

    }

    public static interface ClickListener {
        public void onClick(View view, int position);

        public void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

   static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

        private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        private ClickListener clickListener;

        public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                        clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        }
    }
   /* public void myClickMethod(View v) {
        switch(v.getid()) {
            // Just like you were doing
        }
    }*/

    public interface FragmentDrawerListener {
        public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position);
    }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private Fragment fra;
   // FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    View view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        myImage.setAlpha(50);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar1);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.logofinal);
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
       /* getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);*/
        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

/**
 * Creating all buttons instances
 * */
        // Dashboard News feed button

        /*Button btn_newsfeed = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_news_feed);
        btn_newsfeed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switch(view.getId())
                {
                    case R.id.btn_news_feed:
                        fra= new HomeFragment();
                         break;
                }
            }
        });
        Button btn_friends = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_events);
        btn_friends.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switch(view.getId())
                {
                     case R.id.btn_events:
                        fra= new ContactFragment();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });*/
       // Dashboard Friends button
        Button btn_newsfeed = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_news_feed);

        Button btn_friends = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_friends);

        // Dashboard Messages button
        Button btn_messages = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_messages);

        // Dashboard Places button
        Button btn_places = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_places);

        // Dashboard Events button
        Button btn_events = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_events);

        // Dashboard Photos button
        Button btn_photos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_photos);

        //Button btn_Maps = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_maps);

        /**
         * Handling all button click events
         * */
        // Listening to News Feed button click*/




        btn_friends.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Launching News Feed Screen
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

       // Listening Friends button click

        btn_newsfeed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Launching News Feed Screen
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeFragment.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        // Listening Messages button click
        btn_messages.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Launching News Feed Screen
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MessagesFragment.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        // Listening to Places button click
        btn_places.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Launching News Feed Screen
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FriendsFragment.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        // Listening to Events button click
        btn_events.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Launching News Feed Screen
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CampusFragment.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        // Listening to Photos button click
        btn_photos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Launching News Feed Screen
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactFragment.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
}
   /* public void myClickmethod(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_news_feed:
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeFragment.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }*/


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

        public Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragments.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitles.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if(id == R.id.action_search){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Intent intent;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeFragment.class);
                title = getString(R.string.title_home);
                startActivity(i);

                break;
            case 1:
                i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FriendsFragment.class);
                title = getString(R.string.title_friends);
                startActivity(i);

                break;
            case 2:
               Intent i2=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MessagesFragment.class);
                title = getString(R.string.title_messages);
                startActivity(i2);

                break;
           /* case 3:
                Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FriendsFragment.class);
                startActivity(i1);
                title = getString(R.string.title_department);
                startActivity(i1);

                break;*/
            case 3:
                i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CampusFragment.class);
                title = getString(R.string.title_campus_life);
                startActivity(i);

                break;
            case 4:
                i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactFragment.class);
                title = getString(R.string.title_contact);
                startActivity(i);

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            // set the toolbar title
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
    }
    public void onBackPressed() {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


        alertDlg.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");

        alertDlg.setCancelable(false);


        alertDlg.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();

                    }

                }

        );

        alertDlg.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                // We do nothing

            }

        });

        alertDlg.create().show();
    }
}
```

Would be grateful if anyone helps me.

Comment: Could elaborate a bit more on what this code is supposed to do?

Comment: @Cleb This code is used for naivgation drawer which it calls from main activity. I have added the Mainactivity code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to override the `onRequestDisallowTouchEvent()` method on your `RecyclerTouchListener`.

Try adding this within your `RecyclerTouchListener` class:

```java
@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept)  {
}
```

So.. your code should now look like this:

```java
 public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                        clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                    }
                }
            });

           @Override
           public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept){
            }
        }
```

You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955340/class-must-either-be-declared-abstract-or) for more info.

I hope this helps!

Comment: No sir I am not using any RecyclerTouchListner class. It was working fine but when i run the project from real device this error occurs.

Comment: You ARE using it, in your FragmentDrawer.java file. Look closer.. add the code that I suggest after your `onLongPress()` method.

Comment: Sir i have added the code which you have specified ,but the error remains the same.

Comment: Whoops! I haven't described where to put it well at all, I have updated my answer to show exactly what I mean!

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer sir it works, i have just included this code after the RecyclerTouchListener class

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing one method:

```
onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept)
```

See in: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener.html

Inside your *RecyclerTouchListener* class, you need to add this:

```
@Override
public void  onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
//Any desired code
}
```

Comment: Sir the above code should be put after the RecyclerTouchListener class and then it works fine. Thank you so much.